# Understanding complicated array formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, array

I wanted to remove all letters from a cell, leaving only numbers.After some googling, I found this array formula: `=SUM(MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)`

When I click evaluate, it makes hundreds of true/false statements which are extremely confusing. Can someone break this down and explain what each component does?

Answer (score 1):

Let's step through the Evaluate process together:

In my example, I have the value `abf5fb6` in cell `A2`, which evaluates to `56`.

First step, replace `A2` with value at cell `A2`

Before:

> =SUM(MID(0&**A2**,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

After:

> =SUM(MID(0&**"abf5fb6"**,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

Notice how the text now in enclosed inside a pair of quotation marks. This means that it is text, otherwise known as a *string*.

Now is a good time to briefly explain the `MID` function. This function will simply extract some text from a string. The first argument is the text, or string, that we will start with. The second argument is the start position of where we want to start extracting. The third argument is the number of characters we want to extract for, or the length of our ending result. For example, `=MID("wizlog", 1, 3` will return `wiz` while `=MID("wizlog", 2, 5)` will return `izlog`

So, the next step then concatenates the `0&"abf5fb6"`, because as noted above, the first argument in the `MID` function requires text (again, called a string). But in order to add a number to a string in Excel, you use the `&` symbol.

Before:

> =SUM(MID(**0&"abf5fb6"**,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

After:

> =SUM(MID(**"0abf5fb6"**,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

Now, we will jump to the next `MID` function to replace the other `A2` with it's value again, just like before.

After:

> =SUM(MID("0abf5fb6",LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(**"abf5fb6**,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

Next, we're dealing with the second argument in the second `MID` function, `ROW($1:$99)`. Remember, the second argument in the `MID` function just gives us the starting position. The `ROW` function on the other hand simply just returns the row it is given, so since we pass it the range of 1-99, then it will return to us an array, or a list, of 1-99. This means that we plan to use the `MID` function 99 times, each time starting at a different position from 1 to 99.

Before:

> =SUM(MID("0abf5fb6",LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID("abf5fb6",**ROW($1:$99)**,1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

After:

> =SUM(MID("0abf5fb6",LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID("abf5fb6",**{1;2;3;...;99}**,1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

(To save room, I didn't type out all of the numbers from 1-99, but I'm sure you get the point.)

Now that we have all the pieces to the second `MID` function, we can calculate this part out.

Before:

> =SUM(MID("0abf5fb6",LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--**MID("abf5fb6",{1;2;3;...;99},1)**)*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

After:

> =SUM(MID("0abf5fb6",LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--**{"a";"b";"f";"5";"f";"b";"6";"";"";"";...;""}**)*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

So what just happened here? Well the `MID` function just returns a substring of the string given, starting at the given location, for the specified number of characters. So we gave it the string, `abf5fb6`, gave it an array of starting positions, specifying we only want to extract 1 character. Thus, the function returns to us an array of each character in our string, from 1-99. Since our starting string was only 7 characters long, then the positions 8-99 are just empty, thus why we have all of the empty substrings after, (`"";"";"";...;"";`).

The next function to calculate is the `ISNUMBER` function, but first let's go over an odd feature we do first. Notice how there is a double minus in front our new array. While a single minus sign will reverse the result of an outcome (if `TRUE` then return `FALSE` and visa-vera), but a double minus means to force the string answer into a number. So usually this will result in the answers of `TRUE` to turn into a `1` and a `FALSE` to turn into a `0`, but in this case, we are converting each character in our array to be a number. So entering in `--"a"` will result in `#VALUE!` while entering in `--"5"` will result in `5`.

Thus, when we execute the `ISNUMBER` function:

> =SUM(MID("0abf5fb6",LARGE(INDEX(**ISNUMBER(--{"a"; "b"; "f"; "5"; "f"; "b"; "6"; ""; ""; ""; ...; ""}**)*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

What we are actually executing behind the scenes is:

> =SUM(MID("0abf5fb6",LARGE(INDEX(**ISNUMBER({#VALUE!; #VALUE!; #VALUE!; 5; #VALUE!; #VALUE!; 6; #VALUE!; #VALUE!; #VALUE!; ...; #VALUE!}**)*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

As a result, it turns an array of `TRUE` or `FALSE` indicating if the value was a number or not. Hence we get:

> =SUM(MID("0abf5fb6",LARGE(INDEX(**{FALSE; FALSE; FALSE; TRUE; FALSE; FALSE; TRUE; FALSE; FALSE; ...; FALSE}**)*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)

**Ran out of time**
Well I'm at work doing what I'm not supposed to be doing, and this was as far as I got before I need to actually do something productive today. Hopefully I'll pick back up where I left off later on.

Comment: This is incredibly through and very well written.  Thank you very much, can't wait to see the rest of the answer! I've already learned so much

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We can "unroll" this formula

```
=SUM(
   MID(
     0&A2,
     LARGE(
       INDEX(
         ISNUMBER(
           --
           MID(
               A2,
               ROW($1:$99),
               1
           )
         )*ROW($1:$99)
         ,
       ),
       ROW($1:$99)
     )+1,
     1
   )*10^ROW($1:$99)/10
 )
```

and follow by all the transformations of the operand(s).

First of all, the expression `ROW($1:$99)`
represents an array of increasing natural numbers
`{1,2,...,99}`. It is often used as a convenient 
block to build an array formula.

Next, `A2` here is an address of the input cell,
which contains a text string with mixed numbers,
for example, 
`R824TX01rQ768`.

So, construction

```
MID(
  A2,
  ROW($1:$99),
  1
)
```

means: create an array of all symbols
(strings of length `1`, according to the third parameter in the `MID(...,1)`)
 from the input `A2` <1>.

The elements which index is greater than the length of the string in `A2` are empty strings.

This array of symbols is then prefixed with double minus `--`,
which will turn a numeric symbol into a corresponding number
and other symbols into the error value `#VALUE!` <2>.

Next, a function `ISNUMBER()` operates on that array of mixed chars/numbers
and result in an array of boolean `true/false` values <3>,

which is multiplied element-wise by a familiar `ROW($1:$99)`.
When a `true/false` value is multiplied by the number,
`true` is interpreted as `1`, and `false` as `0`,
thus the result is a numeric array,
which for every character position in `A2`
contains either `0`, if the symbol is not a digit,
or the index, if the character is digit <4>.

Function

```
INDEX(<the array>,)
```

or, expanded,

```
=INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),)
```

takes this numeric array and an empty second argument,
which basically results in the same array <5>.

Expression

```
LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))
```

sorts our array operand obtained from `INDEX(...)` in descending order <6>

Expression

```
MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)
```

first prefixes the string in `A2` with `0` 
and extracts the symbols in the sorted order, starting with the last digit found <7>.

And every digit in the obtained array is multiplied by `10^ROW($1:$99)/10` <8>.

```
MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10
```

<9>

Finally,

```
=SUM(MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)
```

sums all the numbers in the array, which results 
in a desired number <10>.

Not sure, why the repeating construction of `INDEX(<array>,)` is used,
it seems that the formula works without it as well:

```
=SUM(MID(0&A2,LARGE(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)
```

<11>

Perhaps, some compatibility issues?

Comment: First of all, thank you for writing such a long answer. I look forward to reading it in its entierity.  In one of your first few lines though, you wrote `<1>`, what do the "<>" mean?

Comment: @wizlog : The numbers like `<1>` just mean a reference 
to the corresponding column in the attached screenshot,
which displays the result of the step discussed.

Comment: This formula is crazy. However, can it be improved slightly? I think strings are limited to 256 characters, so perhaps `$1:$99` Should be `$1:$256`? Will this hit a value limit?

Comment: @Yorik : Actually, text strings can be much longer than 256,
check out [Excel-specifications-and-limits](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).
The real limit for this kind of formula would be the number of digits in the input text, because of the
numeric accuracy limitations.